# Ubuntu 20.04.06 autoinstall freeze while using packer variables like {{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, hyper-v, packer

Trying to install ubuntu 20.04.06 with packer in hyper-v 2nd generation vm.

When trying use boot_command like this:

```
    boot_command = [
        "<esc><esc><esc><wait>",
        "linux /casper/vmlinuz ",
        "fsck.mode=skip ip=192.168.160.110::192.168.160.254:255.255.255.0::::1.1.1.1 autoinstall 'ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/' ", 
        "<enter>",
        "initrd /casper/initrd<enter>",
        "boot<enter>"
  ]
```

It gets freezed in [image]

waiting 40min still same result,  when I open second tty I can see only blinking dash and nothing more.

also tried use escape characters

```
"fsck.mode=skip ip=192.168.160.110::192.168.160.254:255.255.255.0::::1.1.1.1 autoinstall \"ds=nocloud-net;s=http://{{ .HTTPIP }}:{{ .HTTPPort }}/\" ",
```

same results and its freeze.

Then I tried manually  enter IP of packer host and all works just fine as expected

```
"fsck.mode=skip ip=192.168.160.110::192.168.160.254:255.255.255.0::::1.1.1.1 autoinstall 'ds=nocloud-net;s=http://192.168.160.10:80/' "
```